# How to close window after user agreed with terms and conditions

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

The problem here is that I cannot disable the button before closing it, how can I do that?

```
import tkinter as tk

w_window = tk.Tk()
w_window.title('Introduction')
w_window.geometry("450x100")

def tez():
w_button['state'] = 'disabled'

w_button = tk.Button(w_window,
text='Agree',
font = 'Bold 11',
command=tez)
w_button.pack()
if (w_button['state'] == 'disabled'):
w_window.destroy()

w_window.mainloop()
```

I expected it to disable the button before closing it, but what happened is that it closed without disabling the button.

Comment: Learn more about event-driven programming please. You need to put `if` inside a function, prolly

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: Why don't you simply call `w_window.destroy()` inside `tez()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has indentation errors at the time I am writing my answer, please fix them.

Coming to the point, every `Tkinter` widget has an `after()` method, with the following syntax:

```py
<widget-name>.after(time, callback=None)
```

The `time` argument takes a value as an `int` in milliseconds, and `callback` argument takes a function to repeat after every `time` interval.

For example if `root` is the main window,

```py
root.after(100, my_function)
```

This will call `my_function` function every 100 milliseconds or 1 second. Notice that unlike `sleep()` method, this does not halt the main thread, and executes as an independent thread, so the GUI will not pause.

So what you can do is check for the state of `w_button` after every 50 milliseconds (you can change it as per your wish), and when it gets disabled, the window will `destroy()`.

Here's your full code with the solution implemented:

```py
import tkinter as tk

w_window = tk.Tk()
w_window.title('Introduction')
w_window.geometry("450x100")

def tez():
    w_button['state'] = 'disabled' # fixed indentation

w_button = tk.Button(w_window, text='Agree', font = 'Bold 11', command=tez)
w_button.pack()
def check_state():
    if (w_button['state'] == 'disabled'): # fixed indentation
        w_window.destroy() # fixed indentation

    w_window.after(50, check_state) # after every 50 milliseconds, check_state() method is called

check_state()
w_window.mainloop()
```

Now your code will run as expected. Note that you can make the `destroy()` method to implement faster by modifying the time in `w_window.after()` method to a lesser value.

Hope my answer helps. :)

Refer to this article for further research: [after Method - tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/after-method-in-python-tkinter)